# Numerical integration of triple integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, mathematica, monte-carlo, simulation

I want to compute the following integral

[image]

where the parameters are given by: $\alpha=3.95$, $w_{zeq} = 2.5$, $\sigma_R = 0.32$, $\mu = -0.05$, $A_0 = 0.0032$, $\sigma = 0.548$, $h_0 = 0.001$, and $\nu=0.58$. I've tried to compute it using Mathematica (NINtegrate) however I get the message "Numerical integration converging too slowly, suspect one of the 
following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand". So, I'm not sure if the value obtained is correct or not.

Comment: Is it possible to use Monte Carlo method or any other method to compute the above integral? I just need to check whether the value generated by Mathematica is correct or not.

Comment: Did you try NIntegrate[... Method -> {"MonteCarloRule", "Points" -> 1000000}]

Comment: Thanks user14717 for your comment.